# I'd like to update a state in react every few seconds, but am getting unexpected results

Tags: reactjs

The state property, count, is not increasing by 10 as expected, every second.  It is sometimes increasing by other amounts, becoming quite large quickly.

I tried:

```
          this.setState((state,props)=>
          {count: state.count + 10})
```

```
 class Application extends React.Component {
       constructor(props){
       super(props)
        
       this.state = {
       count: 0
      }
        this.decrease = this.decrease.bind(this)
     }
  
    decrease(){
    
        this.setState(
          {count: this.state.count + 10})
         }
        render() {
          setInterval(this.decrease, 3000);

        return 
        <div>
          <p>{this.state.count}</p>
        </div>;
      }
    }


    React.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Does it increase at all or it just remains as 0?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `componentDidMount` and functional updates for that:

```
class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: 0
    };
    this.decrease = this.decrease.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(this.decrease, 1000);
  }

  decrease() {
    this.setState(prev => ({ count: prev.count + 10 }));
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{this.state.count}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Currently, you adding an interval on every render. Also, you have [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) on `this.state.count` when assigning it to `setInterval` callback.

[image: Edit laughing-bas-tq74s]

Answer (score 0):

Calling setInterval on every render is going to cause it to update more often—every time you render you’re adding another update interval.

One solution would be to use setTimeout instead, and start a new one after each update. Either that or do it in  componentDidMount.